# inserting hash into a specific array location

Tags: ruby, hash

I'd like to insert a hash into a specific location in an array. I have this:

```
arr = [
  {:key1=>"one", :key2=>"two", :key3=>"three"},
  {:key1=>"four", :key2=>"five", :key3=>"six"},
  {:key1=>"seven", :key2=>"eight", :key3=>"nine"}
]
```

and would like to insert this hash into the array

```
{:key1=>"---", :key2=>"---", :key3=>"---"}
```

So that the result is

```
arr = [
  {:key1=>"one", :key2=>"two", :key3=>"three"},
  {:key1=>"---", :key2=>"---", :key3=>"---"},  
  {:key1=>"four", :key2=>"five", :key3=>"six"},
  {:key1=>"seven", :key2=>"eight", :key3=>"nine"}
]
```

Can anyone help please

Comment: What you want to insert is not a hash, nor is it a valid Ruby object.

Comment: You wanted to do an insert, and Ruby Array has an insert method. All you had to do was refer the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use the array insert method.

`arr.insert(1, {:key1=>"---", :key2=>"---", :key3=>"---"} )`

Check out the example here
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-insert

Answer (score 1):

`arr.insert(1,{:key1=>"---", :key2=>"---", :key3=>"---"})`

Comment: missing the closing parenthesis :)